# calling a function with arguement as a string not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function

This is part of my code to display an album on my page.  If I call the function like this

```
<?php   
    for ($key_Number = 0; $key_Number < count($album); $key_Number++) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="ajax_json_gallery("gallery1)">Gallery1</a><br>';
    }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery('gallery1');</script>
```

It works fine.  gallery1 is a file on my server with test photos inside.  If I call it like this

```
<?php   
    for ($key_Number = 0; $key_Number < count($album); $key_Number++) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number])">'.$album[$key_Number].'</a><br>';
    }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number]);</script>
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? 
I need to pass different strings depending on the user so I need to give it a variable.
And yes, my array $album does contain the correct file folder names.

Here is the function that is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_json_gallery(folder){
    var thumbnailbox = document.getElementById("thumbnailbox");
    var pictureframe = document.getElementById("pictureframe");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "json_gallery_data2.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            pictureframe.innerHTML = "<img src='"+d.img1.src+"'>";
            thumbnailbox.innerHTML = "";

            for(var o in d){
                if(d[o].src){
                thumbnailbox.innerHTML += '<div onclick="putinframe(\''+d[o].src+'\')"><img src="'+d[o].src+'"></div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
hr.send("folder="+folder);
thumbnailbox.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}

function putinframe(src){
    var pictureframe = document.getElementById("pictureframe");
    pictureframe.innerHTML = '<img src="'+src+'">';
}
```

And here is the page that gets the photos json_gallery_data2.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$folder = $_POST["folder"];
$jsonData = '{';
$dir = $folder."/";
$dirHandle = opendir($dir); 
$i = 0;

while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if(!is_dir($file) && preg_match("/.jpg|.gif|.png/i", $file)){
        $i++;
        $src = "$dir$file";
        $jsonData .= '"img'.$i.'":{ "num":"'.$i.'","src":"'.$src.'", "name":"'.$file.'" },';
    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= '}';
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

Comment: You might want to try this
`echo '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="ajax_json_gallery(' . $album[$key_Number] . ')">'.$album[$key_Number].'</a><br>';`

Comment: use some advanced event registration methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st:**

`$key_Number` varibale on your server in the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number]);</script>
```

Contains `count($album)` value, which not exists in the array.

---

**2nd:**

If you trying to output php value in this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number]);</script>
```

Then try to enclose output in `<?php ?>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery('<?php echo $album[$key_Number]; ?>');</script>
```

---

**3rd:**

Single quotes does not allow to parse variables in string.

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number])">'.$album[$key_Number].'</a><br>';
```

This ^ line doing not what you expecting.

Try to use double quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return false\" onmousedown=\"ajax_json_gallery({$album[$key_Number]})\">{$album[$key_Number]}</a><br>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections and it works great!  I really appreciated the full code example.

Comment: @JeffK Glad to help. If any onswer on this page helped to solve your issue, then you may accept it as solution. Good luck.

Comment: on 2nd I used $album[0] to show the first album as default.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is mixing server-side and client-side code:

```
ajax_json_gallery($album[$key_Number]);
```

The variables `$album` and `$key_number` aren't defined in JavaScript, so it can't use them.  (I'm sure when it's "not working" it's actually telling you on the JavaScript console that those variables aren't defined.)

To emit values from PHP, you need to surround them with `<?php ?>` tags.  Additionally, since it's a string in JavaScript, it needs to be enclosed in quotes in the JavaScript.  Something like this:

```
ajax_json_gallery('<?php echo $album[$key_Number]; ?>');
```

Comment: He's trying to use the PHP variables in his JS code, as far as I can see. Also, it's not necessary to use `<?php ?>` tags inside an `echo` statement.

Comment: @AmalMurali: I'm not using the PHP tags inside an echo statement, though on a second inspection of the OP's code it looks like there are *two* calls to this JavaScript function.  One inside a loop (which is inside an echo statement), and one outside the loop.  The one outside the loop needs what I described, but I also don't think the loop values are going to be available in that context.  There appear to be several things wrong with the OP's code.